# NServiceBus 2.0 loses first published message when using MsmqSubscriptionStorage

Tags: nservicebus

I am using MsmqSubscriptionStorage in a pub/sub scenario and the first message is lost when the subscriptions has not been stored.  If I watch the debug messages, while running in the GenericHost, I see that all the subscriptions are setup but the first message is never sent to the subscribers.  If more messages are sent, then they are successfully sent to the subscribers (as indicated in the logs)

I am using version 2.0.0.0.

Here is the bus configuration I'm using.

```
var bus = Configure.With(
    new List<Assembly>
    {
        typeof(Configure).Assembly,
        typeof(IBus).Assembly
    })
    .DefaultBuilder()
    .Log4Net()
    .XmlSerializer()
    .MsmqTransport()
        .IsTransactional(true)
        .PurgeOnStartup(false)
    .UnicastBus()
        .ImpersonateSender(false)
        .LoadMessageHandlers()
    .MsmqSubscriptionStorage()
    .CreateBus()
    .Start();
```

Comment: It looks like you're only telling NServiceBus to scan its own DLLs (based on the assemblies passed to With()) - that probably isn't the best idea.

Comment: I omitted the reference to my assembly with my messages def in my example.  The reason I was doing this way is that the folder contains many non .NET assemblies and I would have to have a huge list of exclusions.  If I only list my assembly, I get:  "Type NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage was not registered in the serializer."  I think you are right and it could be related the this usage and am trying to confirm it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own post so no one sees this issue and draws the conclusion that there is something wrong with NServiceBus.  This was a GCE - (Gross Conceptual Error) on my part.  My hosting environment was deferring resolution of a static reference to the Bus.  Changing the initialization of my process to setup the static Bus reference at start up solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you Publish before any subscription has been registered those messages won't have a destination and will be ignored.  You may want to look into the DB subscription storage to have something less transient.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this happen but this is not the case.  The subscribers are running before the Bus.Publish is called.  I don't quite understand why MsmqSubscriptionStorage would be less transient than a DB Subscription Storage.

Comment: Sounds good, looks like you have a lead from above.  As for the storage, it all depends on how you set up MSMQ.  The nice thing about the DB is that it can be easily clustered & replicated(especially between sites).